# Was my answer to this question permanently deleted?

Tags: support

[In John 1:3 why does the author use ἐγένετο instead of ἐποίησεν?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29728/in-john-13-why-does-the-author-use-%E1%BC%90%CE%B3%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%BF-instead-of-%E1%BC%90%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%AF%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%BD)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as permanent deletion (we've been over this before, if you'd had a post deleted you would see it yourself with a red background and deletion notice). You've never had an answer post on that question.

Comment: The system reports that it was modified 20 hours ago by Community. Is there a record of what it changed? Thanks. (I wasn't accusing anyone, just wondering where my answer went. I see also the Christiany.se removed it as well.

Comment: @Ruminator Community didn't change anything. There is a banner under the question that specifies what Community did: *bumped to the homepage by Community yesterday This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.* This is a regular automated process wherein questions that have answers with a score of 0 get bumped so the answers can be reviewed. You can read about it in the sixth bullet [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/390967).